# Thymeleaf th:field is not accepting in <label> tag,it does not showing data

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my project using Spring boot,and Thymeleaf,I tried to post a list of values in a table format,

1) i make a List of Entity,

```
List<EntFlatIncome> flatIncomeList
```

2) Setted into Wrapper class,

```
WrpFlatIncome wrpFlatIncome = new WrpFlatIncome();
            wrpFlatIncome.setFlatIncomeList(flatIncomeList);
```

3) Returing a ModelAndView to "ApproveBillList" HTML page incl List Data

```
ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("ApproveBillList");
modelView.addObject("wrpflatIncome", wrpFlatIncome);
```

In That HTML Page i showing value **Label** instead of Input Box,because the data **IsApproved** Boolean value only need to update Other columns data dont need to Modify by the User
[image: This is a HTML page Design]

When I tried to submit Data using Thymeleaf th:object has only **IsApproved**
data only other column (PaidAmount,paidDate,paymentMode,transactionId,BillAmount)values are NULL only,

In the Label I used to Code Like This

```
<td>
       <label th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].billAmount}"
      th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].billAmount}"></label>
      </td>
```

If i Putted in input box **th:field** with  **disabled** attibute means it also passes NULL only,please Help Me out..Thank You

Here Is The Full HTML Code

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <!-- Body Content Starts -->
  <form id="billformid" action="#"  method="post" th:action="@{/updatebill}" th:object="${wrpflatIncome}">
  
  <div class="table-responsive table-responsive-md"> 
 
 <table class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
     <tr>
   <th>isApproved</th>   
      <th>paidAmount</th>
      <th>paidDate</th>
      <th>paymentMode</th>
      <th>transactionId</th>
      <th>Bill Amount</th>
      
    </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="flatIncomeList,status:*{flatIncomeList}" 
    th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(wrpflatIncome.flatIncomeList)}">
    
       <td hidden="true">
      <input class="form-control" type="text"
       th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].billId}"/>
      </td> 
      
      
       <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  
       th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].isApproved}"/>
      </td> 
      
      <td th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidAmount}">
      <label 
      th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidAmount}"></label>
      </td>
      
      <td th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidDate}">
       <label 
      th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidDate}"></label>
      </td> 
      
      <td th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paymentMode}">
       <label 
      th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paymentMode}"></label>
      </td> 
      
      <td th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].transactionId}">
       <label 
      th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].transactionId}"></label>
      </td> 
      
       <td>
       <label th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].billAmount}"
      th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].billAmount}"></label>
      </td> 
      
      <!-- version not shown in html -->
        <td hidden="true">
      <input class="form-control" type="text"
       th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].version}"/>
      </td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
 </table>
 </div>
 
 <div class="text-center">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
 <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
 </div>
  
  
  
  </form>
  <!-- Body Content Ends -->
   </div>
```

@Controller

```
@PostMapping("/updatebill")
public ModelAndView doUpdateBillApproveStatus(@ModelAttribute WrpFlatIncome wrpflatIncome) 
{
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
    try {
        if(wrpflatIncome.getFlatIncomeList()!=null) {

            //Boolean result = serbillSave.doUpdateApprovedBillList(wrpflatIncome.getFlatIncomeList());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return modelView;
}
```

Comment: you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `th:field` attribute on `label` or `td`. It won't work as expected; the browser will not submit any data for these elements.

Instead you should be using `input`s. It can be readonly:

```xml
<input type="text" th:field="*{myField}" readonly="readonly"/>
```

Or hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{myField}"/>
```

Comment: i tried that ,but table display look is not good,i need to show as a label.Thank you @holmis83

Comment: @VigneshR you can use hidden input + duplicate value in visible element of your choise (a "label").

Comment: ha ha thats what i now did,but i want to know anyother ways to show in Non Editable Text version,..ok i can post my answer pls check it

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know it is right answer,but it works for me

,
i made to show a **th:text** with in td

```
<td th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidAmount}"> </td>
```

To Carryout the data i putted in another td with hidden attibute

```
<td hidden="true">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" 
      th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidAmount}"></input>
      </td>
```

So **td hidden="true"** wont be shown in table display,but it can able to hold the data in **th:field**

Here is code is look like

```
 <td th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidAmount}"> </td>
  <td hidden="true">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" 
  th:field="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidAmount}"></input>
  </td>

  <td th:text="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidDate}"></td>
  <td hidden="true">
   <input class="form-control" type="text"
  th:field ="*{flatIncomeList[__${status.index}__].paidDate}"></input>
  </td>
```

Comment: "How much can you torture a template engine before it explodes in your face" TM